# Why doesn't DataDirectory change on run time

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, local-database

I am tring to connect to a local database with w winform c# application 
when i set my connection string to Data: `Source=C:\Users\PACKARD BELL\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GestionStock\MyApp\Mydb.sdf`
it works fine but when i set it to `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Mydb.sdf` it dosen't work 
i tried to print the connection string with the data directory variable in the console and i found that it dosen't change

i want the connection string to change with the location of the application folder

How can i do that?
thanks in advance

Comment: isn't that %data directory% or something?

Comment: Yes it |DataDirectory| but it doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `|DataDirectory|`: This is the value that is set through the `AppDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", objValue)` method.  An ASP.NET application resolves |DataDirectory| to the "/app_data" folder.

Essentially, if you use the `|DataDirectory|` value, your database must exist inside the `App_Data\` directory in your project.  You can change the default value, but in practice this only serves to confuse other developers who might be expecting the default behavior.

So, instead of

`Source=C:\Users\PACKARD BELL\documents\visual studio 2010/Projects\GestionStock\MyApp\Mydb.sdf`,

it would be

`Source=C:\Users\PACKARD BELL\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GestionStock\MyApp\App_Data\Mydb.sdf`

Comment: I did put my sdf file in an App_Data directory still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

But the sdf file in the folder App_Data

Comment: how can i use it please?

Comment: Just create a folder called App_data in your project or you can choose from the spacial folders menu when you right click on the project in your solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scrap from an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/790410/Using-Environment-SpecialFolder-to-Maximize-Portab) I've wrote:

```
// What's the name of the file you want to work with
var file_name = "parse_me.txt";

// Let's assume you're working with the file on your desktop
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

// This is needed to "paste" the dir and the file name (it'll add the "\" basically).
var file_location = Path.Combine(path,file_name);

// Now you can do:
string[] read_all_lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file_location);
```

Assuming you have the file in there, it should work.