# How can I change my connection string's absolute path to relative path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2013, connection-string

```
<add name="movies_db.mdf" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Movies\App_Data\movies_db.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Hi, I added this connection string in my Web.config page to connect to my "movies_db.mdf" database. I copied the whole path from the properties section when pointing the mouse on the database name in "Server Explorer". Now this has worked on my computer and as I understand it the connection string's path is called absolute path. How can I change it to relative path so it can work and connect on another computer ?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and trying to create a website with a connection to DB.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964195/why-doesnt-datadirectory-change-on-run-time/25964352#25964352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your connection string setting as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="movies_db.mdf" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={%FileName%};Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then in your code use the connection string as follows:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["movies_db.mdf"].ConnectionString.Replace("{%FileName%}",
Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/movies_db.mdf"));
```

Comment: Hi, I made the changes you suggested above and tried it on another computer, but now another problem has appeared :
"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\.net\Desktop\Movies_Project_300521788\App_Data\movies_db.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share." 
How can I solve this problem ?
Thanks for the reply

Comment: This seems more like a file permissions issue. The account running your IIS server (Usually the application pool account user id), does not have access to your desktop. I would be thankful that it doesn't because well... if a web application was allowed to read/modify the contents of the desktop, we'd have a huge security issue. Try placing it inside of somewhere you *know* the IIS Application pool user has access to. For example, for me it's: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite. Basically, put it inside of your web application's App_Data folder. So C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\App_Data.

Comment: Your suggestion has worked perfectly : I just put the the folder in intetpub\wwwwroot and the database was read fine.
Thanks for the help, your explanation helped me understand a number of things I did not know before. With that in place I used your connection string and sqlConnection object and has worked fine.
My question now should I always use that instead of making it an absolute path ? it seems that absolute path only works on one computer and that is pretty useless unless you want it to stay on your computer right ?
Thanks again

Comment: It's a matter of preference but I would say the better solution is to use the application's virtual path with the "~" in front. That way, it can work on a variety of servers and all you have to do to get the absolute path is to use Server.MapPath("~/VirtualPath"). Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score -1):

try this. It works for sql server databases but don't know if work for localdb

```
   <add name="con-string1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=movies_db;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: This will not work for a DB stored in the file-system. His question is regarding a DB in the file-system; not one stored in SQL Server.